# PHP - e-mail being sent to junk on Hotmail

Tags: php

i'm trying to send e-mail using the function `mail()`.

But my email is being sent to junk, and it works perfectly on *gmail*, what am i doing wrong?

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $name .= " ";
    $from = $_POST['from'];
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];;
    $to = $_POST["to"];
    mail($to, $subject, $message, "from: $name \n $from \n");
    echo $name;
}
?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="from" name="from" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="to" name="to" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" />
    <textarea type="text" placeholder="Message" name="message"></textarea>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Basically hotmail has detected your mail as crap and moved it to junk. Nothing special

Comment: You should use a SMTP or check the junk-configuration of hotmail. If this is no solution, check following link: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/221927/Send-mail-to-hotmail-account-via-SMTP-goes-to-junk

Comment: Check that your server IP has not been blacklisted: http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

Comment: Is this script online and reachable in public and not your located in your LAN?

Comment: try to send an email to mail-tester.com and see what's the problem, you're probably missing some headers. also if you can try to send trough an actual mail server (SMTP) instead of sendmail.

Comment: @TD_Nijboer sendmail is a a mail server using SMTP

Comment: Everyone saying sendmail is not a real mailserver or cannot talk real SMTP, pls do your homework *"Sendmail is a general purpose internetwork email routing facility that supports many kinds of mail-transfer and delivery methods, including the Simple Mail Transfer Protocol (SMTP) used for email transport over the Internet."*

Comment: @DanFromGermany you're right. but, what if the account doesn't exists? and has no open relay? which account is used to send?
as the official PHP manual suggests: " If intending to send HTML or otherwise Complex mails, it is recommended to use the PEAR package » PEAR::Mail_Mime."

Comment: @TD_Nijboer your comment is good until the point where you say that sendmail is not a real mail server that's talking SMTP.

Comment: @DanFromGermany i'm sorry, what i probably should have said. use an connection where you can use actual SMTP account login. and yes that is also an option when using sendmail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem could be that the domain name in your $from field doesn't match the server that the email is being sent from.
The IP address that you are sending from could also be on the spam blacklist for the email client provider you are using.

There are some other guidelines that can affect how email clients will detect your email as junk, such as whitespace in the header fields, missing `Reply-To` and `Return-Path` headers etc.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons Hotmail moves your mail to spam, is because you let the user enter the 'from' address. If the domain from which the mail is sent doesn't coincide with the from address in the header, the mail is seen as spam. Some servers reject the mail altogether.

Using [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) sure helps with setting the right headers, but you should never send mails from other domains than your own.

Comment: Or using PEAR::MAIL()

Answer (score 0):

Another thing than using different php libraries, there is also the matter of whiletilsts/blacklists which are lists of domains/ips which mail hosting companies use to quickly distingquish spam from proper mail so they sometimes require you to send some kind of email from admin@domain... to the moderator to prove you're not a spam bot, try checking this for hotmail.

You might want to read: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/domain-whitelisted-hotmail-46827.html

Answer (score -2):

use smtp for sending an email then it will not go in junk

http://www.mendoweb.be/blog/php-send-mail-smtp-server-authentication-required/

Comment: `mail()` actually uses an SMTP on localhost. This answer does not show any effort at all..

Comment: mail() uses sendmail, that uses DNS to find MX record of target domain and delivers there directly. thats it.

and since destination server probably does not know your ip address, especially if it is NATed it may be marked as spam.

Comment: sendmail is an MTA that uses SMTP. `mail()` uses your local default MTA, that can be exim, postfix, not neccesarily sendmail. You can configure  `mail()`  to use gmail too.